# java substring and charAt returns "" and exception respectivly while readng the last character

Tags: java, string, char, substring

```
public class StringDemo{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String str = "this:";
       int a = str.indexOf(":"); // returns 4
       String subStr = str.substring(a+1); // returns "" <empty string>
       String subStr = str.substring(a+2); // throws exception
      int charAt = str.charAt(a+1); // Throws an StringIndexOutOfBoundsExp.
    }
}
```

can any one explain why is it returning ""  and why it throws an exception

Comment: did you read the javadoc for both of those methods?

Comment: Read Javadocs : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29

Comment: i want to know the reason why is it so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.substring(a+1)` returns a substring from `str` STARTING at `a+1` or `5`. Your string doesn't have anything at index `5` so it will return an empty string.

Comment: ok aggree with your answer
but when i try to access a+2 location which is giving me an exception in substring method so string doesnot have anything at the 6th index so why it throws exception

Comment: `.substring()` will return a blank string when you call it with the size of the string, it will simply return a new empty string. Anything greater and it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.substring(a+1)
```

returns the string *after* the given index (`a+1`), which is the string after the colon which is an empty string.

```
str.charAt(a+1)
```

accesses the array value at the position *after* the colon which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't throw `IndexOutOfBoundException` instead it will return **empty String**.
 Same is the case when `beginIndex` and `endIndex` is equal, in case of second method. It will only throw `StringIndexBoundException` when `beginIndex` is negative, larger than `endIndex` or larger than `length of String`.

String subStr = str.substring(a+1); // returns  "" .
                        // Because there is Nothing at that place

Its clearly  [there in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

> "emptiness".substring(9) returns "" (an empty string)

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-substring-in-java-works.html#ixzz2SVu5lyYo

where as `CharAt` throws  Throws:
`IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index argument is negative or not less than the `length of this string`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer first why the result is empty string.

```
Method:substring(int beginIndex)
```

is like saying

```
substring(beginIndex,String.length());
```

the endIndex specified on your argument is 5 and the length is also 5. Thus if you do substring(0,0) or substring(1,1) or substring(5,5), it will always give an empty string because begin and end Index is equal. To put it in simple language, same begin and end index occupies nothing thus result to empty string.

Why the integer 5 is still a valid index? the answer lies on the Java API itself: Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Reference:

[Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)
[String substring() method example](http://javatutorialhq.com/java/lang/string-class-tutorial/substring-method-example/)